# how to get values using gettext() method using webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I am using `webdriver` to get value using `gettext()` method.

HTML code is:

```
<label>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-option="Tshirts" 
 data-filter="global_attr_article_type_facet">
  Tshirts
<span class="num">(4896)</span>
</label>
```

from above code I need `webdriver` to return `4896` value.

I have tried below mentioned code.

```
String number=driver.findelementby(by.xpath("//span[@class='num']")).gettext();
system.out.println(number);
```

but it gives me blank space in return.

Comment: Are you using Java? In your code is it a typo or do you use `findelementby` by intention and is it compiled?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that there are multiple instances of `<span class="num">value</span>`.  Selenium will match the first instance when using `findElement`, and in this case, I suspect the first instance of `<span class="num">value</span>` is either hidden or has a blank for the text.

I think this selector may work better for you:

```
//input[@data-option='Tshirts']/following-sibling::span[@class='num']
```